# Remove Optional Numbering From String with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I am try to create a regex that will capture the token between two capturing groups.

**Example Input**

```
Added experiencevalidator [Java] [Spring]
1.  Added validators [Java] [Spring]
2.  Fixed issues with deletes [JPA] [Java]
```

Basically I want to capture the token between the numbering (1.,2.) and the tag ([Java] [Spring]).

**Expected Captures**

The matcher should return the following for each respective line:

```
Added experiencevalidator
Added validators
Fixed issues with deletes
```

I am currently using this code, which utilizes positive lookaheads and lookbehinds.

```
private Pattern TITLE_REGEX = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\d\\.\\s)(.*?)(?=\\[.*)");

private String cleanseTitle(String title){
    Matcher m = TITLE_REGEX.matcher(title);
    if(m.find()){
        System.out.println("Match found");
        System.out.println(m.group(1));;
    }else{
        System.out.println("No Match");
    }
    return title;
}
```

Each line is passed to the `cleanseTitle` method via the title parameter.  My problem is that I am not sure how to handle the lines that are not preceded by numbering.  The code currently handles lines preceded by numbering properly, however those not preceded by numbering return no match.

Can anyone provide me with a regex that will handle lines preceded by numbering or lines not preceded by numbering?  I am open to any regex solution and I'm not in love with my current regex so feel free to change it.  Any accompanying explanation that can help me learn more about regexs is also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use a capturing group, you don't need lookarounds. I would change the lookbehind to an alternation, to match either the numbering or leading optional whitespace:

```
^(?:\d+\.\s|\s*)(.*?)(?=\[.*)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3394g)

The ordering in the alternation is here important. You need to have the numbering as first alternation, because the second alternative will match all the time.

You can skip also the lookahead and the lazy quantifier with this

```
^(?:\d+\.\s|\s*)([^\[]+)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?3394j)

Comment: This is what I would go with. @fge's solution requires running the string through 2 regexes.

Comment: @Falmarri maybe, but it is probably faster. For instance, I don't need to use a capturing group at all, and I don't need to use a lazy quantifier ;) And I don't need to use lookarounds either. And to conclude, I don't need to do anything if nothing matches, and matches are "fail fast".

Comment: @stema this solution works, I'm going to bench mark both tests, I'll post results and accept the fastest.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I made an improvement to my solution.

Comment: Stema's solution clocked in at about 9ms to run about 60 titles, fge's clocked in around 15ms.  Appreciate both your answers.

Comment: @Stema how does it know what to match with no capturing group?  In regards to the updated solution. I take it this part `([^\[]+)` matches everything preceding the `[`?

Comment: I haven't removed the capturing group, your result is still in group[1]. I just removed the lookahead that stops the match at a `[`, instead I match all characters that are not a `[`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two regexes:

1. replace `^\d+\.\s+` by nothing,
2. replace `(\s+\[[^]]+\])*\s*$` by nothing.

Don't forget to double all backslashes in Java strings, of course.

Note that you do NOT need to test for a match: if the regex does not match, no substitution will take place.

Sample code:

```
private static final String
    BEGINNING_NUMBERS = "^\\d+\\.\\s+",
    ENDING_TOKENS = "(\\s+\\[[^]]+\\])*\\s*$";

private String cleanseTitle(String title)
{
    return title.replaceFirst(BEGINNING_NUMBERS, "")
        .replaceFirst(ENDING_TOKENS, "");
}
```

Comment: I'm not comprehending your solution what do you mean, "replace by nothing"

Comment: See sample code: replace whatever matches with the empty string. If there is no match, nothing will be replaced, so it is basically a no-op.

Comment: Excellent, solution is working.  Going to give it a minute or two to see if anyone else responds before accepting.  Thanks

Comment: One question, what does this portion of the regex `[^]` do?

Comment: It is `[^]]`, really, ie a character class which matches anything but `]`.

Answer (score 1):

With only fixing your regex and not writing a new one, you're matching a number at the beggining. Why not make it optional.

```
(?<=\\d\\.\\s)?(.*?)(?=\\[.*)
```

Comment: Should I also make the period and whitespace optional?

Comment: I edited it. I was trying not to re-write your regex from scratch

Comment: If there is a better way go ahead by all means, your current solution works though.  I'm all for learning.

Comment: One thing I am noticing with this solution is that it now returns the numbering in the capturing group.

Comment: It makes no sense to make an assertion optional.

Comment: I agree, this answer not only doesn't work but is probably a very poor example even if it did. I wasn't reading very closely and didn't notice that the original regex was using lookarounds.